# How do I reassign specific values within a column of a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame, and one of the columns is a mislabeled continent value called americas. I want to reassign all values with United States and Canada as North America, and Every other value labeled as Americas to be reassigned as South America.

```
for (i in g2$country){
   if (i == "United States") {
       g2$continent == 'North America"
   }
}
```

Comment: Use `ifelse` instead of `if/else` i.e. `ifelse(g2$country %in% c("Canada", "United States"), "North America", "South America")`

Answer (score 1):

```r
g2 <- g2 |>
  mutate("new" = ifelse(country %in% c("United States","Canada"),"North America","South America"))
```

If there are more labels in your country variable, you should add another `ifelse()` instead of "South America".

Comment: Nested `ifelse`-statements aren't usally a good idea. `case_when` is a better solution in this case.

Comment: What makes `case_when` better than `ifelse`-statements?

Comment: For _nested_ statements, `case_when` much more easier to read. A downside: it's part of the `dplyr` package, so you need an additional package. Using a single IF-ELSE construct is fine. At least that's my opinion on this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work in a tidyverse frame, you could use case_when:

```
g2 %>%
  mutate(continent = case_when(
              country %in% c("United States", "Canada", "Mexico") ~ "North America",
              TRUE ~ "South America")
         )
```

(that `TRUE ~ "South America"` is how `case_when` handles `ELSE` logic.)

A more generalized solution (if you have lots more than 2 continent labels) would be to build a dictionary tibble `continent_lookup` with columns for country and continent and then `join` that with your current `g2` tibble.